# Let $T=\{c_m\neq c_n: m,n\in \mathbb{N}, m\neq n \}$ in the language $L=\{c_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$. Prove that T is not $\aleph_0$-categorical.

Tags: logic, first-order-logic, model-theory, cardinals

as the title says I am asked to prove the following:

Let $T=\{c_m\neq c_n: m,n\in \mathbb{N}, m\neq n \}$ in the language $L=\{c_n : n\in \mathbb{N}\}$, where each $c_n$ is a constant symbol. Prove that T is not $\aleph_0$-categorical. Prove also that $T$ is $\mathcal{k}$-categorical for each cardinal $\mathcal{k}>\aleph_0$.

I thought a lot about this but I can't manage to prove it. Any help is appreciated :)

Comment: **Hint:** in models $\mathfrak{A}$ of $T$ you might examine the sets $\mathfrak{A}\smallsetminus\{a_i\mid i\in\mathbb{N}\}$ (where each $c_i$ is mapped to $a_i$) and how “different” they can be.

Comment: Ok I think I got it. I can find two countable models where the interpretation of the constants are in bijection but where the rest of the sets are not. While considering uncountable models the rest of the sets are both uncountable, so they can be put in bijection as well. Thank you, it was very helpful.

Comment: You're welcome. Indeed the result relies on the behaviour of infinite sets: if $A$ is infinite with a countable subset $C$, then $\mathop{\rm card}(A\smallsetminus C)=\mathop{\rm card}(A)$ when $A$ is uncountable, but may assume infinitely many different values when $A$ is countable.